# Do canals affect land value

Tags: cities-skylines

The 1.4 patch introduced, amongst other things, canals.

Do canals affect the land value in the same way as shorelines do? I.e can I increase land value in an area by drawing some canals and building around them.

Comment: Found this _[reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/4g0tv6/screenshot_pro_tip_canals_are_really_good_for/)_

Answer (score 2):

No, they do not. At least, not directly. There are a few considerations to make that can still have en effect; but these effects are near-insignificant.

- A quay *slightly* raises the ground (compared to a natural decline into the ocean), and allows a zoned building to be built *slightly* closer to the water's edge. Both of these things will have a positive effect on land value (but again, we're talking about tiny effects).
- Flood barriers don't increase the land value. However, *not losing houses in a flood* can prevent houses from having to be rebuilt; which means that you don't have to wait for them to level up again. In other words, it keeps your cash flow steadier after a flood (but again, tiny effect).